React Native Gifted Charts not animating on data change
I'm trying to use react-native-gifted-charts to create a line chart that animates whenever the data changes. Any time I change the data though the line chart does not animate smoothly like it shows in the examples at https://gifted-charts.web.app/linechart under animate on data change. It just changes in a very jerky manner. Any idea why this might be the case, is it because I'm using expo? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import { LineChart, LineChartBicolor } from "react-native-gifted-charts";
    import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; // Assuming you're using Expo
    import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
    import {ruleTypes,clone} from 'gifted-charts-core';
    const Statistics = () => {
        const lcomp = v => (
            <Text style={{width: 50, color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{v}</Text>
          );
        const dPoint = () => {
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  width: 14,
                  height: 14,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  borderWidth: 3,
                  borderRadius: 7,
                  borderColor: '#07BAD1',
                }}
              />
            );
          };
          const latestData = [
            {
              value: 350,
              labelComponent: () => lcomp('22 Nov'),
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 370,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 460,
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 500,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 570,
              labelComponent: () => lcomp('24 Nov'),
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 560,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 590,
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 490,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 280,
              labelComponent: () => lcomp('26 Nov'),
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 370,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 350,
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 460,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 520,
              labelComponent: () => lcomp('28 Nov'),
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 490,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 370,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 350,
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 460,
              labelComponent: () => lcomp('28 Nov'),
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
            {
              value: 270,
              hideDataPoint: true,
            },
            {
              value: 350,
              customDataPoint: dPoint,
            },
          ];
    
        
        const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState(clone(latestData));
    
        const modify = () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const newData = latestData.map(item => {
                    return {
                        value: 250,
                    };
                });
                setCurrentData(newData);
            }, 1200);
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                const newData = latestData.map(item => {
                    return {
                        value: item.value - 50,
                    };
                });
                setCurrentData(newData);
            }, 10000);
        };
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.title}>
                    <Text style={styles.header}>Statistics</Text>
                    <View style={styles.title}>
                        <Text style={{color:"#5A6256"}}>See More </Text>
                        <Ionicons name="chevron-forward-sharp" size={30} color="#5A6256"/>
                        <Button  onPress={modify} title="Change Data"/>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.stats}>
                <LineChart
                        isAnimated
                        data={currentData}
                        thickness={3}
                        maxValue={600}
                        hideRules
                        hideDataPoints
                        noOfSections={3}
                        animateOnDataChange
                        animationDuration={1000}
                        onDataChangeAnimationDuration={4000}
                        animationEasing="ease-in-out"
                        startFillColor='#b2cfa4'
                        endFillColor='#b2cfa4'
                        startOpacity={0.5}
                        endOpacity={0.1}
                        areaChart
                        verticalLinesColor="grey"
                        xAxisColor="grey"
                        yAxisColor="grey"
                        color="#b2cfa4"
                        />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        stats: {
            backgroundColor: 'beige',
            borderRadius: 20,
            borderColor: '#5A6256',
            borderWidth: 0.2,
            padding:10,
    
        },
        container: {
            padding: 15,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            
        },
        header: {
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight:'600',
            color: '#5A6256',
        },
    
        title: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingHorizontal: 10
        }
    
    });
    
    export default Statistics;


what device did you run the expo app on?

There was an issue with react-native-gifted-charts itself. It has been fixed in version 1.4.23 with this PR.
Please use the latest version of react-native-gifted-charts.
